# How to permanantly and dynamically save data in an html file?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, drop-down-menu, textbox

Ok so I am trying to make a program that allows teachers to edit/design a test and for students to take it.  I made dropdown menues to select type of question and the category (history, english, etc.) and have textboxes to receive the question text. My question though is how to save this text and selections permanently.  My initial thought was to change the contents of a js file variable, but javascript is client side. What is the easiest option as I need this quickly? Please just plain javascript/html, no jquery or jfiddle. Please explain in simple words :). I am no pro. PHP is ok but I do not know it so I will need it to be clear. If you could help, that would be fantastic as I and another guy have not found a simple solution ( at least to our minds).

Answer (score 1):

If your users only use modern browsers (very unlikely), you can use local storage:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

---

Otherwise learn [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX). It allows to save/read data from a server async. That means you don't have to change the page and you can save your data on every selection change.

---

And if you want to have it easy, use a Framework. Because this is a ajax request without a framework:

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Initialize the Ajax request
xhr.open('get', 'send-ajax-data.php');
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){     // Track the state changes of the request
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){ // Ready state 4 means the request is done
        if(xhr.status === 200){ // 200 is a successful return

        }
    }
}
xhr.send(null); // Send the request to send-ajax-data.php
```

And this is a ajax request with a framework (jquery):

```
$.get( "send-ajax-data.php", function( data ) {

});
```

Comment: Local storage would be a good option for saving a single user's data but it looks like this individuals project involves multiple people having the ability to access the data from multiple different locations.  Good thought though, local storage is fun.

Comment: It's somewhat unfair to compare the length of vanilla/jquery if you add tons of comments in one, but not the other and if you make one do something the other doesn't do.

Comment: @Info Bürk: the main intention of this part of the answer was to keep in mind that ajax request without a framework are very complex. My example doesn't even handle browser compatibility. The question was for a simple solution with JS. And I bring up two possible solution and mentioned that it easier with a framework. Or do you mean that a AJAX request without a framework is easier? I changed it any way to fit to your needs.

Comment: @JanHommes No, I definitely agree with the conclusion, but I disagree with reaching conclusions the wrong way. Glad to see you edited it, +1.

Comment: Wow. thanks for the quick response. I may try this out later. Excuse the perhaps amateur question but this data will be available when a new html is loaded, right? Because there will be at least three html files. the opening page, the edit page, and the test page for students.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the above answer, and send your data using ajax call.

or

you can  [save your data in xml file in client side](http://jsbin.com/ufufez/1/edit).

```
  var newXml = "text to be saved"; // your data is here (form the xml).

  //Sets the data in a hyperlink for download.
  $('#DownloadLink')
    .attr('href', 'data:text/xml;base64,' + btoa(newXml))
    .attr('download', 'autounattended.xml');
```

or  you can save the data in json too.

```
  //creates javascript object
 var sampledata  = {'PkId' : 123, 'Name':'sudhansu' };

  //Converts the object to json string.
  var dataTobeSaved = JSON.stringify(sampledata);

  then you can save this data to a file using the above method.
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you slice it, there are a few things that you will need to learn in order to make this work.  So instead of handing you code that you might not understand or be able to implement, I think you would be better served by some references and a simple explanation.

First, you will need to implement a [CGI (common gateway interface)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface).  CGI can be implemented via [Perl](http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/a/hellocgi.htm), [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [Python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm), [JavaScript (with nodejs)](http://nodejs.org/).  There are other languages that can be used, but these are the most common.

After you have a CGI script setup on your server, your client-side application can submit data to the server via a [AJAX request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) or via a [HTML Form submit](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).  Most people use AJAX, but both options work.

Once the data is sent from the client and handled by the CGI script, you will want to be able to interface with the data.  [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) is an acronym for interfacing with data, it stands for [Create, Read, Update, Delete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).  While it is possible to implement this by storing the data in a raw text file, it is generally considered a bad practice.  Thus I would recommend that you look into using some type of SQL database, [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) are a few that are relatively easy to implement (SQLite being the easiest of the three imo).